# Github Pages build failure

Tags: html, github, jekyll, symlink, github-pages

I'm getting the following error about my Jekyll Github Pages reop:
`Your site is having problems building: A file was included in source/blog/index.html that is a symlink or does not exist in your _includes directory.`

[This](https://github.com/int-a/int-a.github.io/blob/master/source/blog/index.html) is the file it is complaining about, and the rest of the code is contained in that repo. I'm confused because the two files it is referencing are in the `_includes` folder, so what could be the issue? The page works fine when I build and run it locally.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi intA you can't load file from blog jekyll is configured to load posts only from _posts? Why do you want to load from 'blog' folder?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It looks like the blog folder contains the index.html page that represents my list of posts. The actual posts are in the _posts directory.

Comment: jekyll uses this project structure http://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/

Comment: that's the reason I was asking why you  want to serve your page from blog folder

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem, same error message, you probably got a post from github stating there is a symlink error, in my case I got this one:

> The symbolic link `/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-linux-gnu/include/ffitarget.h` targets a file which does not exist within your site's repository.

I do not know why this error occurs but I do know a workaround that probably works for you too.

Solution is build your site locally and  only shoot  _site folder to github.

Follow these steps:

1. make a copy of your website folder (this one is your back-up, because your original folder will be reduced to only one folder, yes you guessed right the _site folder
2. in your terminal switch to your original folder and run:`jekyll build --safe`
3. now delete all folders in the directory except the _site folder
4. actually we only want the content of _site folder -> you probably know how to get rid off the folder
5. now it is time to shoot the content to github gh-pages, I assume you already have a github repo.
6. type again in your terminal: `git add .`, `git commit -m "static build"`, `git push origin gh-pages`
7. enjoy your jekyll website hosted on github pages!

Comment: this is an explanation from jekyll why you have to build your site locally, when you use plug-ins: "GitHub Pages is powered by Jekyll. However, all Pages sites are generated using the --safe option to disable custom plugins for security reasons. Unfortunately, this means your plugins won’t work if you’re deploying to GitHub Pages.

You can still use GitHub Pages to publish your site, but you’ll need to convert the site locally and push the generated static files to your GitHub repository instead of the Jekyll source files."

Comment: I would advise against it - that is not the intended use of github pages, you should let github run the build.