# Jekyll Website won't load

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I've been trying for a while to get a Jekyll website running on Github Pages, but it doesn't seem to work. I've been getting the error

> Your site is having problems building: The symbolic link
>   /vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c/libffi-x86_64-linux-gnu/include/ffitarget.h
>   targets a file which does not exist within your site's repository. For
>   more information, see
>   https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-symlink-does-not-exist-within-your-site-s-repository/.

I have already tried it with 9 different Jekyll themes, but none of them seem to work, so I'm clearly doing something wrong. Here are the steps that I am taking

1) Create a new repo and put the files from a Jekyll Theme there, OR fork it from another repo (e.g. https://github.com/iwiedenm/jekyll-theme-massively-src)

2) Git pull it into my computer and make sure I'm on the `gh-pages` branch

3) Run `bundle install --path vendor/bundle`

4) Make sure it was built with `bundle exec jekyll serve`

5) Once it looks good, upload it into Github
`git add *`
`git commit -m 'Test'`
`git push`

Then I go to the repo in the browser and I see the error above, and I can't see the website because of that missing "ffitarget.h" file. When I go look for it in that directory, I am able to find it, but Github doesn't seem to be able to find it.

Nick Shu

PS: Feel free to mark this as a duplicate. I have seen other pages, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401664/github-pages-build-failure) and I tried it, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Github page will use local gems in ***vendor***. If you commit them, you will have errors each time github pages tries to resolve symbolic links.

### From a fresh repository

Add `vendor/**` in your ***.gitignore*** file before you do a `git add . *`.

The dot in `git add . *` forces git to stage dotfiles (.gitignore, ...).

### From an already existing repository containing gems in a vendor folder

- Add `vendor/**` in your ***.gitignore*** file,
- Remove ***vendor/*** files from versioning, `git rm --cached -r vendor/`

You can now stage, commit and push

```
git add . *
git commit -m 'remove vendor from versioning'
git push origin master`
```

**Notes** :

- you can publish ***master*** branch content, as ***gh-pages*** branch is no more mandatory. [See documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/).
- unless you have special needs like debuging, it's not necessary to download gems for each of your project. You can just do a bundle install.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure the `vendor/bundle/` directory has been *excluded*..

By default, Jekyll *excludes* that directory and therefore, it would not care about the contents in your `vendor` directory..

When you fork/clone a repo, there's a possibility that the `exclude:` list has been customized (therefore overriding the default setting). You can ensure `vendor/bundle/` is ignored by Jekyll by adding it to your *custom* exclude list:

```yaml
# Exclude list
exclude:
- README.md
- Gemfile
- Gemfile.lock
- node_modules
- gulpfile.js
- package.json
- _site
- src
- vendor
- CNAME
- LICENSE
- Rakefile
- old
- vendor/bundle/
```

To locally *emulate* how the site is built on GitHub Pages, you can *build* using the `--safe` switch:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --safe
```

Comment: Sorry but excluding vendor/bundle/ doesn't work. You need to gitignore vendor folder.

Comment: @DavidJacquel Please elaborate why its necessary to not check-in `vendor/` files if Jekyll doesn't process them..?

Comment: Because it seems that Github pages is screening gems and breaks on ffi symlink at jekyll startup. Exclude works only at generation time.